# "FileNotFoundError" During Text Recognition Inference using MMOCR in local device

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, ocr

SAR Text Recognition Model was used to custom train the license plates dataset to recognize the Nepali characters. I used Google Drive to train the model to recognize the texts. Now I want to use the weights (file ending in .pth extension) on my local device for inference. The **text_rec_model** contains the path of .pth file

```
infer = TextRecInferencer(weights=text_rec_model)
```

I am thrown this error in the PyCharm Terminal.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/mmocr_tut/mmocr/configs/textrecog/sar/../../../dicts/english_digits_symbols.txt'
```

Is the configuration file saved inside .pth file? If so then how do I edit so that I can run inference using the latest checkpoint, in this case, epoch_85.pth file

Comment: When the computer tells you a file doesn't exist, it's nearly always telling the truth. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name; but we don't have access to your system, so we cannot tell which files exist there or what might be wrong with your attempt.